# Saving binary data into file on model via django storages boto s3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-storage

I'm pulling back a pdf from the echosign API, which gives me the bytes of a file.

I'm trying to take those bytes and save them into a boto s3 backed FileField. I'm not having much luck.

This was the closest I got, but it errors on saving 'speaker', and the pdf, although written to S3, appears to be corrupt.

Here `speaker` is an instance of my model and fileData is the 'bytes' string returned from the echosign api

```
afile = speaker.the_file = S3BotoStorageFile(filename, "wb", S3BotoStorage())
afile.write(fileData)
afile.close()
speaker.save()
```

Answer (score 11):

I'm closer!

```
    content = ContentFile(fileData)
    speaker.profile_file.save(filename, content)
    speaker.save()
```

Turns out the FileField is already a S3BotoStorage, and you can create a new file by passing the raw datadin like that. What I don't know is how to make it binary (I'm assuming its not). My file keeps coming up corrupted, despite having a good amount of data in it.

For reference here is the response from echosign:
https://secure.echosign.com/static/apiv14/sampleXml/getDocuments-response.xml

I'm essentially grabbing the bytes and passing it to `ContentFile` as `fileData`. Maybe I need to base64 decode. Going to try that!

## Update

That worked!

It seems I have to ask the question here before I figure out the answer. Sigh. So the final code looks something like this:

```
content = ContentFile(base64.b64decode(fileData))
speaker.profile_file.save(filename, content)
speaker.save()
```